# Creating a navigationbar in outerthemes with insertnavigation without bulletpoints for frames

Tags: beamer

As mentioned above I am creating my own outer theme and want the navigationbar from insertnavigation. My problem is that every frame is shown as a bullet point but i just need the section with the subsections, not the mini frames.

```
% Frame title


\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{texsx}[1][]
{

\vskip0.4cm
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=0cm]{frametitle} 
  \usebeamerfont{navigation symbols}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox[fill=white](0,0) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
  \fill[MidnightBlue] (0,-9) rectangle(2.5,-8);
  \fill[MidnightBlue!70] (2.5,-9) rectangle(9.3,-8);
  \fill[SkyBlue] (9.3,-9) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,-8);
  \fill[MidnightBlue] (0,0.3455) rectangle (2.5, 1.2);
  \fill[SkyBlue] (0,-0.1) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.35);
  \fill[ MidnightBlue!70] (2.5,0.35) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,1.2);
  \node[anchor= west, white] at (0.3,0.15){\tiny\insertnavigation{0.85\paperwidth}};%
   \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      {\node[anchor=west, white,font=\large] at (2.5,0.61){\insertframetitle};}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\mode<all>``
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It would be much helpful if you can provide a complete example (also called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)) showing what you get.